# `folium.GeoJson` displays all polygons in GeoDataframe but not individual ones

Tags: python, leaflet, folium, jupyter-notebook

`folium.GeoJson` displays all the counties of New York State:

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file("Counties_Shoreline.shp")
m = folium.Map(location=[43.062776, -75.420884], tiles="cartodbpositron", zoom_start=7)
folium.GeoJson(data=gdf["geometry"]).add_to(m)
m
```

However, it fails to display a single county, outputting a map without borders when only the first row data, `gdf["geometry"][0]`, is used:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[43.062776, -75.420884], tiles='cartodbpositron', zoom_start=7)
folium.GeoJson(data=gdf["geometry"][0]).add_to(m)
m
```

This despite the fact that the polygon appears fine, rendering inside Jupyter Notebook.

Data here: http://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/fileserver/?DSID=927&file=NYS_Civil_Boundaries.shp.zip
Shapefile: Counties_Shoreline.shp

[image: NYS counties]
[image: One county shapefile, displayed in Jupyter Notebook]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because  `gdf["geometry"])` is a GeoSerie and `gdf["geometry"][0]` is a shapely geometry (the geometry column is a list of shapely geometries).

The type of data

```
data=gdf["geometry"]
print(type(data)) 
<class 'geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries'>
data= gdf["geometry"][0]
print(data)
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
```

The GeoDataFrame has a projection

```
print(gdf.crs)
epsg:26918
```

but the shapely geometry not and [Impossible to draw GeoJSON that has crs other than 4326](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/481)

A solution is to change de projection of the GeoDataFrame to EPSG:4326 (WSG84)

```
gdf = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:4326") 
print(gdf.crs)
EPSG:4326
m = folium.Map(location=[43.062776, -75.420884],tiles="cartodbpositron", zoom_start=7)
folium.GeoJson(data=gdf["geometry"]).add_to(m) 
m
```

[image]

And

```
m = folium.Map(location=[43.062776, -75.420884], tiles='cartodbpositron', zoom_start=7)
folium.GeoJson(data=gdf["geometry"][0]).add_to(m)
m
```

[image]